# How to replace just first number (delimited with hyphen)?

Tags: javascript, str-replace

Please help! How to replace just first number (delimited with `"-"` or `")"` ) from this example string:

```
var string = "123 - 45 text";
```

or,

```
var string = "123) 45 text";
```

try this code but not ok (result: "123 - text"):

```
var result = string.replace(/[0-9] -/g, "");
```

or,

```
var result = string.replace(/[0-9]\)/g, "");
```

I want to result just like: `45 text` without `123 -`, or `123)`.
Thank's!

WORKING !!! :)  `.replace(/[0-9]+ -/, '')`
  and,
 `.replace(/[0-9]+\)/, '');`

Thank's everybody, especially  @Tushar,  best simple answer: Missed +

I'm finish my project: [this is](http://andrei-petrica.ro/mobileradio.php)

Thank's "stackoverflow" for help!

Comment: Missed `+` quantifier on numbers, `string.replace(/[0-9]+ -/, '')`. Split by `-` and get second element from array.

Comment: Why did you have that "g" flag ? Please look at the documentation instead of trying code at random. A solution: `var result = string.replace(/^[0-9] -/, '');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "123 - 45 text";
string.split(" - ")[1]
=> "45 text"

var string = "123) 45 text";
string.split(") ")[1]
=> "45 text
```

Comment: Thank's, but my string differs from one format to another, since this is a response received from an Icecast server, uncontrollable me. Plus I already use a split (artist + title).
Usually the string is like "artist - song," but sometimes it's the form described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function as defined below

```
 var str = "123 - 45 text";
 var r = str.split(' - ');
 console.log(r[1]);

45 text
```

or substring function

```
var result = str.substr(str.indexOf('-')+1);
console.log(result);

45 text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indx = string.indexOf(')');
var result = string.slice(indx === -1 ? 0 : indx + 1);
```